# How to update a state in redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux-toolkit for managing cart operations of an e-commerce project.

There are two properties in products named `availableQuantity` and `cartQuantity`. When I add a product to cart, its `availableQuantity` gets reduced by 1, and `cartQuantity` increases by 1.

A little bit of more explanation, when I click on `Add to cart`, it will check whether that product is present in cart previously or not. If it's already there, it will increase `cartQuantity` by 1 and return the new state that holds increased `cartQuantity`.

But I'm unable to achieve this in my code.

Here is the related piece of code:

```
state.map((product)=>{
          if (product.id == action.payload.id) {
            console.log("4th");
            console.log("product.cartQuantity:", product.cartQuantity);
            return {
              ...product,
              cartQuantity: product.cartQuantity + 1
            };
            
          } else {
            console.log("5th");
            const updatedPayload = {
              ...action.payload,
              cartQuantity: action.payload.cartQuantity + 1
            };
      
          // Push the updated payload into state
            state.push(updatedPayload);
            
          }
        })
```

And here is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/github/muhammadfuaad/redux_toolkit/code

Answer (score 1):

`state.map(.....)` doesn't actually update the state. A value, e.g. a new array, is returned but nothing is done with this new array.

If I'm reading the code correctly this second condition should be checking if `state` already contains a matching product by `id` property, and if so, update *that* product object, otherwise, append the product as a new product.

Here's a suggested refactor to first search the `state` array for the product. If the product is already there, mutate it, otherwise append a new product object to the array.

Example:

```js
addToCart(state, action) {
  const { id, cartQuantity } = action.payload;
  const product = state.find(product => product.id === id);

  if (product) {
    // Matching product found, update product quantity
    product.cartQuantity += 1;
  } else {
    // No matching product, append new product to array
    state.push({
      ...action.payload,
      cartQuantity: cartQuantity + 1
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Can you please suggest a solution for "remove" button in cart as well?

Comment: @Fuaad Do you mean the `removeFromCart` action?

Comment: @Fuaad You pass the entire cart item to the action `dispatch(removeFromCart(item));`, so the filtering should probably check for id specifically, e.g. `state = state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);`. Alternatively you could just pass the item id to the action, something like `dispatch(removeFromCart(item.id));`. Does this make sense?